# Why is my block not showing up on the Blocks page?

Tags: 7, blocks

I don't remember where exactly my return needs to be.  It had worked at one point, but stopped at a random time.  Google'd and didn't find my answer.

```
function bobby_name_generator_block_view($delta = '') {
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'bobby_name_generator':
      $block['subject'] = t('Generate Bobby Name');
      if(user_access('access content')) {
        $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('bobby_name_generator_form'); // insert bobbyname variable here!
      }
      return $block;
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks OK... Is all of this in bobby_name_generator.module? And do you have bobby_name_generator_block_info() as well?

Comment: I would also suggest to set a $block['content'] for the users who don't have the 'access content' permission. For example, `$block['content'] = '';`

Comment: marcvanged: yes, it is.  I can enable the module. No, I have no hook_block_info() set. Will try that.

Comment: Eлин Й.: I will also add that.

Comment: added both of you guy's suggestions and they did not help

Comment: Could you please update the question with your hook_block_info as well.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example for hook_block_info found in examples module. This defines the existence of block and this will make the block show up in the block page. You could use hook_block_configure to provide additional fields for you block in block page and save the it using hook_block_save.

```
function example_block_info() {

  $blocks['example'] = array(
 'info' => t('Example: configurable text string'),
 'cache' => DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_ROLE,
 'status' => TRUE,
 'region' => 'sidebar_first',
 'visibility' => BLOCK_VISIBILITY_LISTED, 
 'pages' => 'node/*',
 );

return $blocks;
}
```